# Run a shell command that is inside a project folder from Grunt task

Tags: node.js, shell, cordova, gruntjs

I have a shell command `./node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova` which is accessible from the project root.

I also have a set of config files for Grunt which are located in `./config` folder.

Now I am trying to run cordova from tasks and want to use it as an alias, so in Gruntfile.js I have it like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    buildDir: 'build/interim_builds',
    publishDir: 'build/publish',
    cordovaCommand: './node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova',
    ...
```

})

Then, from a task I run it like this:

```
mobileApp_create: {
    cmd: '<%= cordovaCommand %> create <%= mobileAppProjectDir %>'
}
```

As a result I get this error:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

If I replace

```
cordovaCommand: './node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova'
```

with

```
cordovaCommand: 'node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova'
```

Then I see this error:

> 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

So, I suppose it can be something with relative paths and how Grunt works with them? Where do I dig to fix this issue as I need to use local installation of cordova, not global.

Comment: does it work if you use full paths?

Comment: It works if I use `cordova create <%= mobileAppProjectDir %>` which runs globally installed cordova if it's available, but doesn't work if I run it as `./node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova create <%= mobileAppProjectDir %>`

Comment: Maybe try using this instead: https://github.com/csantanapr/grunt-cordovacli.

Answer (score 0):

You could try fully resolving the path at runtime, that way there are no relative paths:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    buildDir: 'build/interim_builds',
    publishDir: 'build/publish',
    cordovaCommand: path.resolve('./node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova'),

    // ...
  });
  // ...
};
```